# An intuitive explanation for the negatives of divergent summations?

Tags: sequences-and-series, philosophy

I am looking for an intuitive explanation for why divergent summations (that are always increasing) have finite values assigned as negative.  An example that is beyond "because the math says so" kind of answer.

As examples, the following summations are always increasing and divergent:

$$1+2+3+\dots n+\dots=-\frac1{12}$$

$$1+2+4+\dots2^n+\dots=-1$$

-[*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series)

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^n=\frac1{1-a}$$

If you input $a=2$, you get the result I predicted.  If you input any $a$ such that $|a|<1$, the summation makes sense, logically, but it doesn't everywhere else.

As for the first one, there are multiple places its been seen (*Big Bang Theory*, the TV show, for example) and by googling $1+2+3+4+5+6+\dots=-1/12$, you should get results as too why.

And as you will notice, they are negative.  However, I look for the answer to the question "*why* they are negative according to multiple agreeing summation methods, which are considered *good* or *strong* methods".

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: Aarrrrghhhhhhh! What is the fascination with the $-{1\over 12} $ thing?

Comment: It appears I need to explain my math a slight bit more...

Comment: @copper.hat That fascination came through varying methods that are very rigorous and beyond my ability to perform.

Comment: @user247608 You see this appearing both on the Wikipedia (the examples have their own wikipedias) and in other places.

Comment: Its just plain wrong.

Comment: @copper.hat But it is not a matter of whether or not it is wrong, because the methods used to get the answer are indeed right (if the summation makes sense), so in a sense, they should work for everything else, at least mostly, because indeed some summation methods fail under certain circumstances (which does not include whether or not it makes sense).

Comment: The summation doesn't make sense. The equality is only valid for $|a|<1$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes!  The summation DOESN'T make sense, but by using MANY different methods like the zeta function or such, we can easily see that the predicted answer for $|a|>1$ does indeed hold true!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34891/discussion-between-simple-art-and-copper-hat).

Comment: @Simple Art : I told you sooner that the answer was : analytic continuation. when traversing a pole, an analytic function will change of  complex argument,  so if $\sum a_n f_n(s)$ has a pole at $s = \sigma$ then $\sum a_n f_n(\sigma+\epsilon)$ will have a different complex argument to $\sum a_n f_n(\sigma-\epsilon)$, thus explaining why your analytic continuation summation methods often has a different sign to the $a_n$ when applied to a divergent series $\sum a_n$

Comment: @user1952009 could you put that into an answer with intuitive reasoning?

Comment: @user1952009 Aw, that really disappoints.  I guess I'll get started on learning analytic continuation then...

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the few examples you've seen come out as negative is just a coincidence, not a general fact.  Any "reasonable" summability method is linear (if the method gives values to $\sum_n A_n$ and $\sum_n B_n$, then it gives $\sum_n (A_n + B_n)$ the value $\sum_n A_n + \sum_n B_n$) and regular (it agrees with ordinary summation for convergent series).  Take any series with positive terms that your method gives a negative value, add positive numbers to  finitely many terms, and you'll get a series to which the method gives a positive value.

Comment: This still doesn't explain *why* they came out negative, as logical reasons argue they shouldn't have.

Comment: I also note that you sort of cheated the question.  By rearranging or changing terms, the summation may take *any* value, thus, you are no longer evaluating the same summation.

Comment: @SimpleArt: By a similar argument, if you have any divergent sum of nonnegative numbers whose "sum" is positive and finite, you can find another one whose sum is negative.  Indeed, just replace finitely many of the terms with $0$ (such the sum of those finitely many terms is greater than the value of the original infinite sum).  So there is no summability method that gives always positive or always negative values to divergent sums of nonnegative numbers.

Comment: "So there is no summability method that gives always positive or always negative values to divergent sums..."  True, but when many different and strong methods all point to the same answer, there must be a *reason* as to why they all point that way.  Furthermore, it is commonly agreeable that we can assign such values to summations that diverge like such.  @EricWofsey

Comment: Of course I wasn't evaluating the same summation.  I'm simply saying that "it comes out negative" is not any kind of general rule.  You have so far given **two** examples where a summability method gives a negative result.  It's like looking at Condaleeza Rice and Hilary Clinton and asking "why is every Secretary of State female?"

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, but there are myriad examples of such summations coming out negative, most of which are either a) accessible online or b) they don't contribute to the fact that such summations come out negative.  I just want an explanation to at least explain *why* summation methods at least agree on this odd negative answer when it should be infinite.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I like your answer but I'll add the idea that when skirting the pole of an analytic function, it changes of complex argument. because those summation methods for divergent series transform the sequence into an analytic function and skirt a pole to get a value, the complex argument is different so there is a bias for a change of sign. (I can't do simpler @SimplerArt)